# Under which conditions would you see the MOST lake effect precipitation?

Tags: meteorology, geophysics, geochemistry, earth-system, cloud-microphysics

It's well known that the Great Lakes produce large amounts of precipitation in the Fall.  When cold polar air moves over the lakes it causes large amounts of relatively warm moist air to rise, condense and fall as either rain or snow on shore.

Under which conditions would you expect to find the MOST precipitation?

1. A polar air mass of 0 degrees centigrade moving over a great lake that has a water temperature of 10 degrees.

OR

2. A polar air mass of -5 degrees centigrade moving over a great lake that has a water temperature of 5 degrees.

Comment: Is this a homework question or something you're simply interested in?  Either way, may be helpful to add your thoughts to the question

Comment: Do I add my thoughts here?  This is not a homework question.  Im genuinely trying to understand the conditions which lead to lake effect precipitation snow at certain times of the year and not others.

Comment: I'm under the impression that the warmer the water the more water vapor there is and thus more precipitation.

Comment: Thanks for encouraging me to reframe my question